# oracle apex giving me an error when using INSERT INTO to add data to tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an assignment due in a few days but cannot remember coming across this error before, im sure its something tiny that ive skimmed over but could someone take a look?

error is :

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 590 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 576 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033

ive tried rewriting single lines but it will not take any code that i put into it. The code i have written is in asterisks (bottom 14 lines) it works fine without these lines so i cannot figure out why. Im a newbie to this kind of stuff (first year uni) so any help would be appreciated!

````
CREATE TABLE vet(
vetno           NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
vetname     VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
vetaddressln1   VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
vetaddressln2   VARCHAR2(20),
vetpostcode     VARCHAR2(8)NOT NULL);

DROP TABLE client cascade constraints;
CREATE TABLE client(
clientno        NUMBER(6)PRIMARY KEY,
surname     VARCHAR2(15)NOT NULL,
firstnames      VARCHAR2(15)NOT NULL,
clientaddressln1    VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
clientaddressln2    VARCHAR2(20),
clientpostcode      VARCHAR2(8)NOT NULL);

DROP TABLE animal cascade constraints;
CREATE TABLE animal(
animalno        NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
name            VARCHAR2(15)NOT NULL ,
sex         VARCHAR2(6),
dateofbirth     DATE,
species     VARCHAR2(30)NOT NULL ,
clientno        NUMBER(6) REFERENCES client(clientno));

DROP TABLE consultation cascade constraints;
CREATE TABLE consultation(
consultationno  NUMBER(6),
consultationdate DATE NOT NULL,
animalno NUMBER(6) REFERENCES animal(animalno),
vetno NUMBER(6) REFERENCES vet(vetno),
Outcomenote VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL );


INSERT INTO vet VALUES (001,'James Herriot','Skeldale, High St', 'Yarm', 'YM3 6WP');
INSERT INTO vet VALUES (002,'Siegfried Farnon','61 Farnby Mount', 'Yarm', 'YM3 6WD'); 
INSERT INTO vet VALUES (003,'Danielle Chang','North St', 'Leeds', 'LS6 3NG');
INSERT INTO vet VALUES (004,'Emma Milne','87 Arncliffe Road', 'Harrogate', 'HG5 5HY');
INSERT INTO vet VALUES (005,'Harry Cooper','15, Coniston Avenue', 'Leeds', 'LS11 4PE');


INSERT INTO client VALUES (0034,'Wong','Judy','Flat 5, Victoria Av', 'Leeds', 'LS5 9PL');
INSERT INTO client VALUES (0035,'Spencer','Tom','4, Broad Lane', 'Harrogate', 'HG4 9DL');
INSERT INTO client VALUES (0036,'Hamza','Farhan','35A, Waterloo Cres', 'Harrogate', 'HG3 3FD');
INSERT INTO client VALUES (0037,'Cummins','Dominic','184, Queenswood Rd', 'Bradford', 'BR3 2GD');
INSERT INTO client VALUES (0038,'Stuart','Moira','77, Westgate', 'Leeds', 'LS1 4KL');

** INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00100,'Elsie','M', 01-FEB-13, 'PERSIAN CAT', '0034');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00101,'Thurston','M', 15-MAY-11, 'MAINE COON CAT', '0034');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00102,'Jeff','F', 11-SEP-19, 'NORWEIGAN FOREST CAT', '0035');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00103,'Monkey','M', 16-SEP-99, 'BOMBAY CAT', '0036');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00104,'Terry','M', 11-MAY-14, 'RED-FOOTED TORTOISE', '0037');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00105,'Emilia','F', 29-OCT-19, 'RED-KNEE TARANTULA', '0038');

INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001001,14-jan-20,'00101','001','Given antibiotics');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001002,11-JUL-20,'00101','002','Given respiratory tablets');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001003,08-JUN-20,'00102','003','Given antibiotics');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001004,11-AUG-20,'00103','005','Saline Drip');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001005,11-SEP-20,'00104','001','Laid 3 eggs');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001006,17-NOV-20,'00102','004','Given antibiotics');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001007,11-DEC-20,'00105','004','Moult Assistance');
INSERT INTO consultation VALUES (001008,04-OCT-20,'00101','005','Given antibiotics');** ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about invalid dates. The way you tried to do it is wrong - not just because it didn't work, but because you wanted to insert them as strings (only if they were enclosed into single quotes). You should insert **dates**.

One option is to use date literal which is always in format `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00100,'Elsie','M', date '2013-02-01', 'PERSIAN CAT', '0034');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Another is to use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO animal VALUES (00101,'Thurston','M', to_date('15-MAY-11', 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english'), 'MAINE COON CAT', '0034');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

The same goes for the `consultation` table.